# How exactly do music boxes work?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

One of my villagers told me that if I take a Giant Clam Shell and one of K.K. Slider's songs to Cyrus, he'll make me a music box. Doing some research on the internet, this does seem to be true, but what I can't find is if you can ever get that piece of music back.

Given that pieces of music in this game are also items that you can display on the wall, this is kind of important to me. Currently, you can take any piece of music and insert it into a music player (stereo, record player, etc.) and it will keep it there for you, as a form of storage, and then you can just choose whatever you want to play from the list of songs.

If I create a music box out of a song, will it only play that one song forever? Is there any way to get my piece of music back? If there is not, will K.K. let me request that same song again so I can get another copy for use in my regular music player/to hang on my wall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Music Box**

The Music Box is actually a family of furniture items, only obtainable by the method you mentioned. Like all other furniture from Cyrus, it is not possible to take one of his products apart into the original materials/furnitures used to make it.

When Cyrus creates the Music Box, the result is a colourful version of the Giant Clam Shell that, whenever opened, will play a little music-box-like version of your song, before closing shut once more.

You can think of the Music Box as a larger, physical, standalone counterpart of the song used to create it, as the Music Box will retain its name when created.

**Additional Copies of Music**

As for obtaining another copy of the song, if you have access to the *Timmy & Tommy Shopping Catalog* from upgrading the Nooklings' shop at least once, you'll notice that there is a category in the catalog for music.

Although you cannot order Music Boxes this way, all of the K.K. records you have ever received or will receive in the future will be recorded in the catalog. Each of these records can simply be ordered from the catalog for 3,200 bells.

Therefore, by purchasing your additional copies from the catalog, you are free to request new pieces of music from K.K.Slider each week.

Comment: You can buy music direct from the catalog?! finally!

Comment: Moreover, if you have other players in your village you can leave songs lying about for each other to pick up and add to your catalogs.