# How do I get music for my home?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I recently received a music player from one of my villagers, but when I tried to turn it on, it said that I "didn't have any music on me". How can I "get music on me"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can receive music by going to [Club LOL](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Club_LOL) once it is open on Saturday evenings after 8pm. Once there, you can talk to K.K. Slider and [depending on what you decide to do](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123043/how-can-i-request-music-from-k-k-slider), you can either receive a random song or a song of your choice to take home.

In your inventory, songs look like a yellow music note. Interact with your music player with it in your inventory and you'll be able to load the song into it to play and eject it later if you decide to do something with it (like hang it on your wall or [make it into a music box](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123041/how-exactly-do-music-boxes-work)).

Answer (score 2):

K.K. Slider hands out a "boot" of a song when you request it. If your inventory is full, you won't be able to retrieve it. When you have it in your inventory, just go up to any of you **24** walls (yes, I counted) and hang up the song.